# After conversion to VB, 'is an event and cannot be called directly.'

Tags: c#, vb.net, raiseevent

The code below is part of project to save exceptions globally.  I have converted this from C# to VB with both SharpDevelop and with Telerik's Code Converter, and I get identical results.

Searching through Stackoverflow, I found this question: "'Why won't this C# convert to VB?', which address the same error I have and shows a simple answer, but doesn't show how to use it - at least so I would know what to change.

What I'm getting is an error on 'ONWRITETODATABASE'.  The complete error is: 'Public Shared Event OnWriteToDatabase(type As String, text As String)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

What do I change to make this work?  (The caps are mine.)

```
Public Delegate Sub DatabaseWriteEventHandler(type As String, text As String)
Public Shared Event OnWriteToDatabase As DatabaseWriteEventHandler

Protected Function OnWriteToDatabase() As Boolean

    _logToDatabaseOK = False

    If ONWRITETODATABASE IsNot Nothing Then
        Try
            RaiseEvent OnWriteToDatabase(_exceptionType, _exceptionText)
            _logToDatabaseOK = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            _results.Add("LogToDatabase", ex.ToString())
        End Try
    Else
        _results.Add("LogToDatabase", "No subscriptions to OnWriteToDatabase event")
    End If

    Return _logToDatabaseOK

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to include the "IsNot Nothing" check (and note Ben N's observation that you don't need it), you can reference the hidden VB event field:

```
If OnWriteToDatabaseEvent IsNot Nothing Then 'the event followed by "Event"
```

Comment: Dave & @Ben N: the procedure is trying to write error information to a database.  If it fails then it will write error information to a local file (last resort and harder to get to).  So I do need the IsNot Nothing check.  I really don't know what you mean by 'the event followed by "Event".  How would you write this out?

Comment: It's written exactly as I've specified: "If OnWriteToDatabaseEvent IsNot Nothing Then". (VB adds a hidden field named the same as the event followed by 'Event' - you normally don't use it, but it fits your requirement).

Comment: Hi Dave - thanks for your response.  However, I've only been using .Net for about year now, and obviously your skill is way beyond mine.  I truly do not know what you mean here.  Could you create an answer and rewrite this code so that the error is removed?  Once I see what you're doing, then I'll be in a better position to learn how it works.  Thanks!

Comment: All I'm suggesting is that instead of "If ONWRITETODATABASE IsNot Nothing Then", use "If OnWriteToDatabaseEvent IsNot Nothing Then".

Comment: Thanks Dave!  That did it - now I can search to learn more about how this works.

Comment: I think the hidden event field in VB is kind of obscure, but I'm sure that Microsoft documents it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

First up, events in VB are not handler collections; they're just something you can listen to with `AddHandler`. Therefore, it's not possible to know (with the simple translation given) whether anybody heard your raising of the event. Also, `As` clauses are not valid after events. What I think you should do is replace the first two lines with this:

```
Public Shared Event OnWriteToDatabase(DataType As String, Text As String)
```

Then, remove the null check and the `_logToDatabaseOK` stuff. (While you're at it, change the `Function` into a `Sub`, getting rid of the return.

Comment: That’s not true, VB knows `Custom Event`s, which make precisely this possible.